# One ip, several subdomains on several virtual machines

Tags: dns, ip, routing

I don't have a lot of knowlege on administratino but here is my situation:

I have a big server with only one IP address. On this server I have 9 virtualbox  machines. I want all these domains to point on all different machines:

```
www.mysite.com => 10.8.0.10
api.mysite.com => 10.8.0.20
pro.mysite.com => 10.8.0.30

dev-www.mysite.com => 10.8.1.10
dev-api.mysite.com => 10.8.1.20
dev-pro.mysite.com => 10.8.1.30

test-www.mysite.com => 10.8.2.10
test-api.mysite.com => 10.8.2.20
test-pro.mysite.com => 10.8.2.30
```

1. I thought that by configuring dns I could redirect each subdomain using a different port ...  ip:80 ip:81 ip:82 ... ip:89
   -> but it turns out I was wrong
2. Then I thought with nginx I could redirect sub-domains to virtual machines... 
   I didn't found the correct solution

Can you give your best advices for this precise situation svp ?

Answer (score 0):

> Then I thought with nginx I could redirect sub-domains to virtual machines

Yes, that's how nginx's "reverse proxy" function works.

On the host server, define `server { … }` blocks for all your subdomains. Instead of specifying a document root path, use `proxy_pass` to point nginx to each of your virtual machines. (The virtual machines must be using host-only or bridged networking.)

For your example, you can use:

```
server {
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.10;
    }
}

server {
    server_name api.mysite.com;
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.20;
    }
}

etc.
```